# JavaFX2: Webview: Fatal error

Tags: webview, javafx-2, fatal-error

I am working on the samples provided by oracle on their website for webview [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm#CEGGECFG). The webview has a "Help" link on the bottom right. Whenever I click on that, the application closes and I get a dump screen with content as below:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005bf97c7a, pid=65032, tid=163660
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b17
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xf7c7a]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Home\Documents\workspace\myFx\hs_err_pid65032.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Environment: Windows 7, 8 GB RAM, i5 processor.
Any pointers?